# AutoHotKey: How to get list of available values from drop down list?

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to automate a website to get data. Usually if I know in advance what are the possible value from the drop down list, I can hard code them in my script.

But if I don't know what are the values, is there an elegant way to dynamically obtain the drop down list values?

Working sample from: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=15574

```
select name="ConnectDTO.EvaluationGroupId" id="ConnectDTO_EvaluationGroupId" style="width: 260px;" required="yes" data-val-number="The field Evaluation Group must be a number." data-val="true"><option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="4">ccpdmanagement</option>
<option value="7">AM Northern</option>
<option selected="selected" value="3">cwplanning</option>
<option value="1">mnplanning</option>
<option value="2">msplanning</option>
<option value="9">LCC</option>
<option value="6">powerquality2</option>
<option value="8">AM Southern</option>
<option value="5">tcoqueries</option>
</select>
```

When my script arrived on the page after loadIE(wb), is there a way to "get" the list of selection - such as ccpdmanagement, AM Northern etc...?

I know how to select them once the option is known in advance only.

```
pwb.document.getElementById("ConnectDTO_EvaluationGroupId").Focus()
pwb.Document.GetelementById("ConnectDTO_EvaluationGroupId").value := "1"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=35467
Althought the Author stated he has a problem with the code (stated not work for some reason).

But for my purpose - to retrieve the list of all the drop down list option. It worked fine.

```
myDropDownList := wb.document.getElementById("your_dropdown_ID")

loop % myDropDownList.length
{
    test := myDropDownList[A_Index-1].value
    MsgBox %test%
}
```